# Nestjs websocket port by configuration and cors

Tags: nestjs

I wonder how to a specific port according to the config service provider https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways ? For e.g, I want to listen to 8500 in my production environment but 8080 in my staging environment.

And how to allow cors on, because when I connect to the socket-server in the different domain it show  `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status`.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?? I'm facing this as well

Answer (score 3):

```
const options = {
  cors: {
    origin: ["example1.com", "example2.com"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
}
@WebSocketGateway(options)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This is a partial answer, it does not explain how the port can be dynamically set.